# C++: How to output data into columns from an iteration loop

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I'm having trouble figuring how to output the data generated by running a loop twice, into two columns.

I'm generating 100 random dice rolls, and outputting the count of how many times each roll gets. And I do this twice through.

My goal is to get two sets of the count and output it so that it looks like:

"one: (count of first set) (count of second set)

two: (count of first set) (count of second set)

three: (count of first set) (count of second set)

and so on...

This is my code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int seed, random, count_one (0), count_two(0), count_three(0), count_four(0), count_five(0), count_six(0);

cout<<"Input the random seed: ";
cin>> seed;
srand(seed);

for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {random=(rand()%6)+1;
        if (random==1)
            count_one++;
        if (random==2)
            count_two++;
        if (random==3)
            count_three++;
        if (random==4)
            count_four++;
        if (random==5)
            count_five++;
        if (random==6)
            count_six++;
        }
        cout<<"First Set"<<"\t"<<"Second Set "<<endl;
    cout<<"one "<<count_one<<endl;
    cout<<"two "<<count_two<<endl;
    cout<<"three "<<count_three<<endl;
    cout<<"four "<<count_four<<endl;
    cout<<"five "<<count_five<<endl;
    cout<<"six "<<count_six<<endl;
    cout<<" Set 1 Avg."<<"\t"<<"Set 2 Avg. "<<endl;
    }

return 0;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!! Thank you so much :)

Comment: you're going to need to store the results and then iterate over the result set to print results from each run side-by-side.

Comment: Adding to the comment above, you are using `i` as index for both loops, the internal loop will modify the external loop, causing trouble. You probably want to use two different variables to index each loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to a count variable for each set and number. Then you can simply put the output after your for loops and thus generate the appearance of columns.

Probably you want to use for that a two dimensional array, since this has two direct benefits for you:

- Definition of Variables is shorter
- You don't need your if instructions.

This would then look similar to this:

```
int seed;
int count[2][6] = {{0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0}};

cout<<"Input the random seed: ";
cin>> seed;
srand(seed);

for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
   for (int j = 0; j < 100; ++j) {
      count[i][rand() % 6]++;
   };
};

cout << "First Set" << "\t" << "Second Set " << endl;
cout << "one " << count[0][0]<< "\t" << count[1][0] << endl;
cout << "two " << count[0][1]<< "\t" << count[1][1] << endl;
...
```

Further improvements would be two put the Strings of the numbers names in an Array, too. Thus you could put most of the output

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in c++, you can use vectors too. I would move the loop that loops to a hundred into a function. That function runs and fills a vector with the counts calculated, and then just call that function twice. After that you can run your printing routine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

float getCounts (vector<int> &counts) {
    float average = 0.0f;

    // Initialize all counts to be output to zero
    counts.clear();
    for (int idxDieNumber=0; idxDieNumber<6; idxDieNumber++) {
        counts.push_back(0);
    }

    // The run the loop you already had, but instead of printing here,
    // just save the results in the vector passed
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        int random=(rand()%6)+1;
        // instead of the original code: if (random==1) counts_one++; , etc
        counts[random-1]++;   // counts[0] corresponds to die face 'one', etc
        average += random;
    }

    return average/100;
}

int main()
{
    // we substitute count_one, count_two, etc in your code
    // by two vectors, each stores the count in each loop
    vector<int> countsPass1;
    vector<int> countsPass2;
    float averagePass1, averagePass2;
    int seed;

    cout<<"Input the random seed: ";
    cin>> seed;
    srand(seed);

    // Instead of the two loops, call the function twice, passing the
    // desired vector and the average for each pass
    averagePass1 = getCounts (countsPass1);
    averagePass2 = getCounts (countsPass2);

    cout<<"First Set"<<"\t"<<"Second Set "<<endl;
    cout<<"one   "<< countsPass1[0] << "\t" <<countsPass2[0] << endl;
    cout<<"two   "<< countsPass1[1] << "\t" <<countsPass2[1] << endl;
    cout<<"three "<< countsPass1[2] << "\t" <<countsPass2[2] << endl;
    cout<<"four  "<< countsPass1[3] << "\t" <<countsPass2[3] << endl;
    cout<<"five  "<< countsPass1[4] << "\t" <<countsPass2[4] << endl;
    cout<<"six   "<< countsPass1[5] << "\t" <<countsPass2[5] << endl;
    cout<<" Set 1 Avg. " << averagePass1 << "\t"<<"Set 2 Avg. "<< averagePass2 <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Note that your averages might be skewed away from `3` if `RAND_MAX` in your system is not an exact multiple of 6 (which most likely it will not be).